# VB.NET: How to access a session variable from a public class?

Tags: vb.net, class, session, public

I'm working on an ASP web application that has both code-behind pages and separate classes not associated with any .asp page.  In the code-behind pages, I manage several different session variables, one of which is Session("debug").  For example:

```
    'Have we created a session debug variabe yet?  If not, create one!
    If Session("debug") IsNot Nothing Then
        _debug = TryCast(Session("debug"), DebugControl)
    Else
        _debug = New DebugControl
        Session("debug") = _debug
    End If
    'This is the debug control.  Uncomment this to turn debugging on
    _debug.isOn = True
```

In one of the public classes, I attempt to use the session variable programmatically in the class constructor:

```
    Public Class SQLControl
        Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
            Private _debug As DebugControl

            Public Sub New()
                If HttpContext.Current.Session("debug") Is Nothing Then
                    _debug = New DebugControl
                    HttpContext.Current.Session("debug") = _debug
                Else
                    _debug = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Session("debug"), DebugControl)
                End If
            End Sub
```

However, when I build the application, I get the following (line 26 is highlighted as the error):

```
Server Error in '/dev' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 24: 
Line 25:     Public Sub New()
Line 26:         If HttpContext.Current.Session("debug") Is Nothing Then
Line 27:             _debug = New DebugControl
Line 28:             HttpContext.Current.Session("debug") = _debug
```

I've read several threads describing similar problems, but most of them suggested using the HttpContext.Current.Session() method, which I'm already doing (I've also tried System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session, with the same results.)  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

David

Comment: Is there a reason you don't pass the current session in a parameter?

Comment: Well, the instantiation of the debugControl needs to be written to by every method in every class (it's for maintaining a first-failure debug log), so it's passing it on every function call seems like a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If by "separate classes not associated with any .asp [sic] page" you are implying that they contain methods for a WebService, you can tell it that you [require use of the session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#vbtskusingwebmethodattributeenablesession) with a decoration, e.g.

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
 Public Function AddToBasket(ByVal filename As String) As String
    Return BasketController.AddItem(filename, HttpContext.Current).ToString
End Function
```

Comment: No, it's not a web service.  It's just .vb file in the App_Code directory.  I tried the webMethod anyway, but ran into a whole slew of diferent problems.